# create, play midi file in android using a custom sf2

Tags: android

I am trying to create an app that can play/create/modify a midi file but the standard instruments are not complete.  I have the sf2 files.  Can someone guide me where i can look for what i need build this app please. Is fluidsynth is the best option?

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Also looking for an answer to this.